# Why can't phpmyadmin upgrade from 4.1.8 to the latest version 4.1.14?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, upgrade

I informed my host to help upgrade the phpmyadmin but what they tell me is that the latest version of phpmyadmin is not integrated into or compatible with cPanel (11.42.1) thus, its failure to upgarde.

I will be very glad and much appreciative of any other possible solution on how to get phpmyadmin upgraded to the latest version.

Thanks very much in advance!!!

Comment: Some more information please - error logs, steps and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your host to assist you with this.

Go to http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php

Click on phpMyAdmin-4.1.14-english.zip and save the download. Extract the zip and upload it into your site to a folder like /pma/ (i.e. http://mydomain.com/pma/)

Rename config.sample.inc.php to config.inc.php and edit it to match your settings.

That's all required to get the latest phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Latheesan, many many thanks for your kind response and answer to my query, which is very useful. Even though I'm not a techie like you, but I will try and follow your steps and if not, relay it to my host. Thanks once again, Latheesan!

Comment: By the way, Latheesan, where do I locate the config.sample.inc.php to edit to config.inc.php? I have searched my cpanel account but can't seem to locate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider is correct. The latest version of PHPMyAdmin isn't compatible with cPanel yet. Since cPanel is used by a large amount of hosting providers, they can't leave anything to chance and therefore they must be 110% sure that a program is safe and secure before upgrading it. The release cycle for PHPMyAdmin is also alot shorter than cPanel, so it's not unusual to have the version of PHPMyAdmin integrated with cPanel alot older than the latest version of PHPMyAdmin. As Latheesan pointed out, you can install the latest version of PHPMyAdmin yourself. Assuming your hosting provider uses automatic cPanel updates, you can keep eye out on the [cPanel v11.42 change log](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/11.42+Change+Log) to see when it gets updated.

Comment: Thanks to you, Ub3rst4r, for your contribution which goes to allay my fears as I thought, once the cpanel got upgraded, phpmyadmin also had to be upgraded automatically without knowing that they were two different platforms. I am certainly following Latheesan's lead. Thanks!